# How to read XML elements c# (sample code provided)

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML sample that I want to read the data. I only provided one "project" element but this can have many "project" inside the "projects" root.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<projects>
  <project>
    <details>
      <projectName><![CDATA[CxWtGZxYT]]></projectName>
      <uniqueID>Pt144</uniqueID>
      <collaboratingList>
        <collaboratingOrganisation id="5318" value="EpCyxCv RvGxrXAYXGpA xCxWtGZxYT"/>
        <collaboratingOrganisation id="0000" value="EpCyxCv RvGxrXAYXGpA xCxWtGZxYTd"/>
      </collaboratingList>
      <researchOutputList>
        <item>
          <pubDate>2014-02-04T00:00:00+00:00</pubDate>
          <title><![CDATA[rGDEZ]]></title>
          <link>link</link>
          <guid>guid</guid>
          <description><![CDATA[uGDB BDstA rGDEZ]]></description>
        </item>
        <item>
          <pubDate>2015-08-04T00:00:00+00:00</pubDate>
          <title><![CDATA[AERx CApCYZ.]]></title>
          <link>link</link>
          <guid>guid</guid>
          <description><![CDATA[vwtpY]]></description>
        </item>
      </researchOutputList>
    </details>
  </project>
</projects>
```

I can read the `<projectName>` and `<uniqueId>` but cannot `<researchOutputList>` and `<collaboratingList>`. I am not sure what I am missing or if my XML structure is correct. My codes below:

```
[Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("projects")]
    public class BulkProjectRoot
    {
        public BulkProjectRoot()
        {
            BulkProjectDetails = new List<BulkProjectData>();
        }

        [XmlArray("project")]
        [XmlArrayItem("details")]
        public List<BulkProjectData> BulkProjectDetails { get; set; }
    }

 [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("details")]

    public class BulkProjectData
    {
        public BulkProjectData()
        {
            ProjectResearches = new List<ProjectResearchOutputs>();
        }

        [XmlElement("projectName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("uniqueID")]
        public string ProjectUniqueId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("researchOutputList")]
        public List<ProjectResearchOutputs> ProjectResearches { get; set; }

    }

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("researchOutputList")]
public class ProjectResearchOutputs
{
    public ProjectResearchOutputs()
    {
        ResearchItemsList = new List<ResearchOutputItems>();
    }

    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<ResearchOutputItems> ResearchItemsList { get; set; }

}

   [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("item")]

    public class ResearchOutputItems
    {

        [XmlElement("pubDate")]
        public DateTime? PublishDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("title")]
        public string ResearchTitle { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("link")]
        public string ResearchLink { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("guid")]
        public string ResearchGuid { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("description")]
        public string ResearchDescription { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reasearchlist deserializes fine with Linqpad, but you are missing the collaboration information in your `BulkProjectData` class.

```
void Main()
{
    var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf - 8""?>
   <projects>
     <project>
       <details>
         <projectName><![CDATA[CxWtGZxYT]]></projectName>
         <uniqueID> Pt144 </uniqueID>
         <collaboratingList>
           <collaboratingOrganisation id = ""5318"" value = ""EpCyxCv RvGxrXAYXGpA xCxWtGZxYT"" />
              <collaboratingOrganisation id = ""0000"" value = ""EpCyxCv RvGxrXAYXGpA xCxWtGZxYTd"" />
               </collaboratingList>
               <researchOutputList>
                 <item>
                   <pubDate>2014-02-04T00:00:00+00:00</pubDate>
                             <title><![CDATA[rGDEZ]]></title>
                             <link> link </link>
                             <guid> guid </guid>
                             <description><![CDATA[uGDB BDstA rGDEZ]]></description>
                           </item>
                           <item>
                             <pubDate>2015-08-04T00:00:00+00:00</pubDate>
                                       <title><![CDATA[AERx CApCYZ.]]></title>
                                       <link> link </link>
                                       <guid> guid </guid>
                                       <description><![CDATA[vwtpY]]></description>
                                     </item>
                                   </researchOutputList>
                                 </details>
                               </project>
                             </projects>";

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BulkProjectRoot));        
            var result = (BulkProjectRoot)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));            

            result.Dump();
```

[image]

Comment: I have the codes but was not able to paste it here sorry. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Jsut make this change -

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("details")]

public class BulkProjectData
{
    public BulkProjectData()
    {
        // Not a list

        ProjectResearches = new ProjectResearchOutputs();
    }

    [XmlElement("projectName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("uniqueID")]
    public string ProjectUniqueId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("researchOutputList")]
    public ProjectResearchOutputs ProjectResearches { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Amit Kumar Ghosh,  
I already changed that line but still does not return the researchoutputlist. The list count is 0.

Comment: This is also correct and I just have to implement ICloneable to get the data.